# Category API for products django

Tags: python, django, api

I have two models: Category, Products. And I want to create a separate url link like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/sneakers for each category to retrieve products from different urls. Using foreign key I can separate them but don't really know how to give them a url. Could you help me with this, please?

what I expect to see in API is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/sneakers

[
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Nike AirMax',
    'brand': 'Nike',
    'price': 200,
    'category': sneakers
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Adidas Yeezy',
    'brand': 'Adidas',
    'price': 300,
    'category': sneakers
  }
]

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/t-shirts

[
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Black Nike T-Shirt'
    'brand': 'Nike',
    'price': 50,
    'category': t-shirts
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Black Adidas T-Shir',
    'brand': 'Adidas',
    'price': 40,
    'category': t-shirts
  }
]
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HezretSaryyev, your original question was different. I've edited this answer by your changed question.

You can do something like this using djangrestframework:

As example:

Your models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barcode = models.IntegerField(default=None, validators=[MinValueValidator(10000000), MaxValueValidator(99999999)], unique=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Your serializers.py

Here is in `serializers.py` you should use this import `from rest_framework import serializers`, `from .models import Category, Product`

```
class CategoryNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)


class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class ProductDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'brand', 'category', 'barcode', 'image')


class CategoryListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Your views.py

Here is in views.py you should use this import `from rest_framework import generics`, `from rest_framework import views`, `from rest_framework.response import Response`

```
class CategoryListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategoryListSerializer


class CategoryDetailAPIView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, name):
        products = Product.objects.filter(category__name=name)
        serializer = serializers.ProductDetailSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class ProductListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductListSerializer


class ProductDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'name'
```

Your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('categories/', views.CategoryListAPIView.as_view(), name='category-list'),
    path('categories/<str:name>', views.CategoryDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),
    path('products/', views.ProductListAPIView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
    path('products/<str:name>', views.ProductDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Does your answer require using Django REST Framework?

Comment: Yep. I assume in this question @HezretSaryyev wanna build API using Django Rest Framework.

Comment: That seems like a good assumption. Since the OP didn't mention DRF, I suggest adding a sentence to your answer to make that assumption more explicit.

Comment: Thank you @Merdan but we are still having the same error we got before **ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'sport_store.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issueis probably caused by a circular import.**. I will try creating a new project and build it from zero. I will let you know ab the results. Thank you one more time!

Comment: You can write you main(project) urls.py file like this:

`
import store_app
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('store_app.urls')),
]
`

Comment: @HezretSaryyev, did you do that part of code, how I explained for your question? Did it work as expected?

Comment: @HezretSaryyev, as I said in my answer, your original question was different and I've edited this answer by your changed question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to register a URL with a placeholder that assigns part of the path to a variable:

```
# urls.py

urls = [
    path('api/categories/<string:category>', views.product_by_category, name=product_by_category)
]
```

Now django will send a `category` parameter to your view that you can use to get the products you want:

```
# views.py

def product_by_category(request, category):
    # get the products and serialize them as JSON or render a template to HTML
    pass
```

You will need to replace `pass` with the appropriate logic to return the correct response.